# ajax way of rendering does not refresh all the values in posts?

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller,

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.upvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end

def downvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.downvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

### _post.html.erb:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div id="voting_div">
    <%= render 'voting', post: post %>
  </div>
  ....
  ....
<% end %>
```

### _voting.html.erb

```
<%= link_to dislike_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true %>
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

### upvote.js.erb

```
$("#voting_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('posts/voting', post: @post)) %>")
```

### downvote.js.erb

```
$("#voting_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('posts/voting', post: @post)) %>")
```

So everything works fine so far, when i vote the first post, it is working fine in ajax way, so does the downvote. It refreshing voting partial for both upvote and downvote. But not for all the posts. Its just working fine for the first post. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Can you please some one help me?

When I manually refresh the page, the value has been successfully stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-use HTML ids like that, you need unique ones to reference a unique post to find it, and update it.  Rails has a helper `dom_id` to create a reasonable ID for these purposes.

Tweak your posts file like so:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div id="<%= dom_id(post) %>">
    <%= render 'voting', post: post %>
  </div>
  ....
  ....
<% end %>
```

And your JS partials to reference it:

```
$("#<%= dom_id(@post) %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('posts/voting', post: @post)) %>")
```

And you should see better results.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Still I don't understand the JS Partial reference. Why there is two hash symbols in it? Can you please explain it? I just did the same way to my code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Well the first `#` is because you're searching for an ID, and the second starts a string interpolation in Ruby.  But that's wrong because you're using ERB, I didn't notice that.  I've updated my post, try that.

Comment: Wow thank you very much. It's work like a charm. You are a STAR :-)